# Lookup activity in an Azure Data Factory Data Copy Source - Syntax Error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Working through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal

I've one Lookup activity called GetCurrentWatermarkValue with sqlReaderQuery:

```
Select WaterMarkValue as CurrentWatermarkValue\nfrom WatermarkTable
```

I've another activity called GetNewWatermarkValue with sqlReaderQuery:

```
select max(createdon) as NewWatermarkValue from shipment
```

I'm then trying to use them both in the source for a Data Copy activity using

```
select *
from Shipment
where CreatedOn > '@{activity('GetCurrentWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.CurrentWatermarkValue}' 
and CreatedOn <= '@{activity('GetNewWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkValue}'
```

The Preview data button is greyed (but enabled when i remove the where condition) so there is obviouusly something wrong

After I've set the sink i try to set up the Mapping. Clicking Import schema on the Mapping tab gives:

```
A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'GetCurrentWatermarkValue'.'. Activity ID:98794aa9-c866-48d6-b9ff-9cb277bac6ed
```

I thought maybe I should be using the add dynamic content option but that just gives

```
Query is required
```

I've read somewhere that the when First Row Only is set on the Lookup activity the text after firstRow. should be [TableName] but that doesn't seem right.

Lookup:

```
{
    "name": "GetCurrentWatermarkValue",
    "type": "Lookup",
    "policy": ...,
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": "Select WaterMarkValue as CurrentWatermarkValue\nfrom WatermarkTable"
        },
        "dataset": {
            "referenceName": "WatermarkTable",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Lookup:

```
{
    "name": "GetNewWatermarkValue",
    "type": "Lookup",
    "policy": ...,
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": "select max(createdon) as NewWatermarkValue from shipment"
        },
        "dataset": {
            "referenceName": "ShipmentsTable",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Data Copy:

```
{
    "name": "ArchiveShipments",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "GetCurrentWatermarkValue",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "GetNewWatermarkValue",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "policy": ...,
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": {
                "value": "select *\nfrom Shipment\nwhere CreatedOn > '@{activity('GetCurrentWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.CurrentWatermarkValue}' \nand CreatedOn <= '@{activity('GetNewWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkValue}'",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSink"
        },
        "enableStaging": false
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "ShipmentsTable",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "ShipmentArchiveTable",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a syntax issue, try this is the copy activity query:

```
@{CONCAT('select * from Shipment where CreatedOn > ', activity('GetCurrentWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.CurrentWatermarkValue, ' and CreatedOn <= ', activity('GetNewWatermarkValue').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkValue}
```

Dont use a mapping unless you want to manually set it, if column names are the same, then just click "Clear".

Hope this helped!